# How to get author's Discord Tag shown

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

How do I display the user's Name + Discord Tag? As in:

I know that;
`f"Hello, <@{ctx.author.id}>"`
will return the user, and being pinged.
(@user)

And that;
`f"Hello, {ctx.author.name}"`
will return the user's nickname, but WITHOUT the #XXXX after it.
(user)

But how do I get it to display the user's full name and tag?
(user#XXXX)

Answer (score 1):

To get user#XXXX you can just do `str(ctx.author)` (or just put it in your f-string and it will automatically be converted to a string). You can also do `ctx.author.discriminator` to get their tag (XXXX).

Answer (score 1):

Below I have listed most, if not all, of the ways you can use `ctx.author`, as well as what it gives.

```py
    await ctx.send(f"Hello {ctx.author}") # author + number discriminator
    await ctx.send(f"Hello {ctx.author.display_name}") # nickname of author of message
    await ctx.send(f"Hello {ctx.author.mention}") # mention the author (ping)
    await ctx.send(f"Hello {ctx.author.id}") # author's user id
    await ctx.send(f"Hello {ctx.author.discriminator}") # the numbers from author#0001
```

[image: ctx.author things]